# PHP code completion in c9

Tags: php, cloud9-ide

In my company we're in stage of exploring c9 IDE's possibilites. Our main programming language is PHP and everybody considers code completion feature like a must-have thing. But it seems that c9 doesn't have this feature. Are we right? If yes, is there a solution? For example I know that c9 has some plugin capabilities so doesn't exist a plugin for that? Or just some other way how to turn on PHP code completion in c9?

Added:

I meant, there's a kind of autocomplete function, but it's very dumb. It can only suggest name of a function or a class but that's it. It doesn't show possible parameters, a short description what function do etc. In most cases I know what's a name of a function (roughly) but I don't know correct order of parameters.

Comment: I can't get it to work either.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud 9 does have auto complete. You must save your file first so it knows what language the file is in.